# Получить все документы, а при равенстве (одинаковости) - более поздние

Tags: mongodb

Фабула: Работает парсер спортивных состязаний. По кругу. По определенной логике, спортивное состязание заноситься в БД. Т.е., в каждом цикле парсинга, состязание может попасть, а может и не попасть в БД.

Необходимо получить все состязания из последних двух циклов парсинга. Но, если состязание попало в оба цикла - то только из последнего. В этом и есть проблема.
Пример документов:

```
  {
    "command1": "A",
    "command2": "B",
    "parseCount": 0
  },
  {
    "command1": "A",
    "command2": "B",
    "parseCount": 1
  },
  {
    "command1": "A",
    "command2": "B",
    "parseCount": 2
  },
  {
    "command1": "C",
    "command2": "D",
    "parseCount": 1
  },
  {
    "command1": "E",
    "command2": "F",
    "parseCount": 2
  },
```

На выходе надо получить последние 3 документа из списка выше. В документе также есть поля: время матча и ObjectId

https://mongoplayground.net/p/-9gz4zOnudW

Comment: вам такой запрос не подойдет: https://mongoplayground.net/p/JHr6F-yXCyU ?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, хм.. так то, запрос соответствует условию. Но мне бы получить  документы со всеми полями. В реальности их же больше